# Index return duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, indexing

I am making a timetable system and I am currently on student timetables.

I want to see when a student has a clash at the same period. Here is the example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Z613_G1FjkP6cYXmgNLFfdCPa39LOZEuQQZiMG5gzw/edit#gid=0)

I am aware of the risks that come with sharing google sheets online.

Currently i have this code to find classes from an overview sheet `=IFERROR(INDEX(OVERVIEW!A$3:A,MATCH(TRUE, REGEXMATCH(OVERVIEW!A$3:A, TEXTJOIN("|",1,$E$3:$E)),0),1),"FREE")`

However, the above only returns one topmost outcome, and does now allow me to see if there are clashes.

Please advice <3

Comment: The shared sheet has *restricted access*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Slightly adjusting the formula you shared:*

***Class***:

```js
=join("; ",filter(regexextract(OVERVIEW!A3:A,"(.*?) "),regexmatch(OVERVIEW!A$3:A,textjoin("|",1,E3:E))))
```

***Subject***:

```js
=join("; ",filter(regexextract(OVERVIEW!A3:A,"\((.*) \("),regexmatch(OVERVIEW!A$3:A,textjoin("|",1,E3:E))))
```

***Teacher***:

```js
=join("; ",filter(regexextract(OVERVIEW!A3:A,"\(([^\(]*)$"),regexmatch(OVERVIEW!A$3:A,textjoin("|",1,E3:E))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much dude, appreciate it <3

Comment: hi i forgot to add the room, how can we do that? (IE. get 07MA01 @ BG01; 07EN01 @ B101)

Comment: Use `(.*?) \(` in place of the current `(.*?) `